# How to update the scope value without using $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have using custom directive

```
<users stats="stats"></users>
```

When we change the scope object from main controller, i have updating directive scope value also

```
app.directive('users', function(){
    var directive = {};
    directive.restrict = "E";
    directive.templateUrl = "templates/partials/users_stats.html";
    directive.scope = {stats:'='};
    directive.controller = "userStatsCtrl"
    return directive;
});
```

So, Inside the directive controller, i am doing some func. like

```
app.controller("userStatsCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.$watch('stats', function(newValue) {
      if (angular.isDefined(newValue)) {
        .....
      }
    });
})
```

So here, i am using $watch to listen the scope, If it is update, I will do the some perform.

my question is, I dont want to use watch to listen the scope, If scope gets updated, i need to do some perform.

So how to update scope value without using scope.$watch

Comment: Why do not you use `$watch`?

Comment: It will affect to whole scope object. But, here particular object only going to change. Performance criteria.

Comment: Better going to use $watch, unless you have tons of them you won't have any performance problems. Furthermore if you want to watch something more precise in your object go for $scope.$watch{function(){ return stats.a}, function(newValue){[process...]});

Answer (score 0):

When ever "scope.stats" value get changed in your main controller, you can broadcast an event and receive the same event in your directive and do operation what ever you want.
Example code for broadcast an event:

```
$scope.$broadcast('yourEventName');
```

Receive an event in directive:

```
$scope.$on('yourEventName', function(){

});
```

Comment: scope is not updated. If i do update on that scope, not affecting here.

Comment: When page loads, that time data only coming from scope

Answer (score 0):

how about trying:

```
<users stats="stats" ng-change="onUserStatChange($event)"></users> 
                           or
<users stats="stats" ng-blur="onUserStatChange($event)"></users>
```

and then in controller:

```
$scope.onUserStatChange = function(event) {
    //event.whatever
}
```

Comment: If i use ng-change="onUserStatChange($event)", im getting   Error: [$compile:ctreq]

Comment: If you use ng-change you must use ng-model along with it.